# jQuery find out when scrollable div has enough content to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

If I have a css with scrolls set, how can I use javscript to find out that if there is enough content for the div to be scrollable?!

What I mean is if there is not enough content so that the div would actually scroll, then I would like to find that out with jQuery

Comment: why you need this ? what you want to do. There could be some easier way of achieving what you want !

Comment: I was going to add some effects to the scrolling. So these divs should be invisible but only visible if there is enough content to scroll!

Comment: Do you want to know if that div is scrollable or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ujiwah/787/edit)

```
if( element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
    element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth){
   // your element have overflow i.e div has enough content to scroll
}
else{
  //your element don't have overflow i.e div has not enough content to scroll
}
```